# Keycloak resource protection recommendations

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

I'm writing web services in Spring Boot and I use Keycloak to protect the application. The app will expose API to manage restaurants.

In **Keycloak** I have two roles: **admin** and **manager**.

A user with **admin** role can CRUD restaurants. The same company has multiple restaurants and each restaurant has a manager. **I want users with manager role to be able to edit only their restaurant** (*the restaurant they manage*).

According to my understanding of Keycloak's documentation I have to use **Resource** with **Permission** but they stated that:

> [] you can also have a different resource named Alice’s Banking Account, which represents a single resource owned by a single customer, which can have its own set of authorization policies.

To do that I have to create a resource like this `/api/restaurants/12345` but the thing is that I can't hardcode an ID like this.

For now I protected my endpoint like this in spring boot:

```java
http
  .authorizeRequests()
  .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/api/restaurants/*").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "MANAGER")
  .anyRequest().permitAll();
```

This means that any manager from any restaurant can edit another restaurant. I want to limit that to their restaurant only (*the restaurant they manage*). **How can I do that in Keycloak** if at all possible?

Comment: Why can't you hardcode an ID? You need some identifier for each restaurant. Any system managing authorizations would need it.

Comment: I want users to be able to add restaurants even after deployment. If I harcode it, this means that after creating a restaurant they will have to go in Keycloak and create a resource. I just think this can be complicated to use. Is it common practice?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [User managed access (UMA)](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/#_service_user_managed_access). It allows to manage the access permission for each resource.

The permissions can be managed with the user's authentication. So if a user enters a new restaurant you can automatically grant access permissions to him without involving a process with elevated privileges.

The best introduction is probably the [Photoz example](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/tree/latest/app-authz-uma-photoz). Instead of restaurants, it's about photo albums.